# Make DocFX only generate for one build configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docfx

I want DoxFX to generate docs only when I select the build configuration "Release+Docs" because it wastes a lot of time when testing otherwise.

I've added this line to the docfx.console.targets, but it seems ineffective. The docs are generated anyway.

```
<BuildDocFx Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' != 'Release+Docs|AnyCPU' ">false</BuildDocFx>
```

How do you correctly disable it?